# subquery with max

Tags: sql

```
select substr(phone,0,3) as area_code
from customer
where (select max(count(area_code)) 
         from customer);
```

why have error here? how to fix? it says missing expression..

Comment: Hi! Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52156798/edit) your question and add the tag for the database you are using (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server?). Also, while editing your question, please show us some example data to see WHY it gives you an error. This way we can help you better. 
Don't hesitate on looking thru the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or in 
the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be sure about how to ask questions.

Comment: Also, it seems odd to have a `SELECT MAX...` in your WHERE without comparing the result with something. WHat do you want to do with your WHERE?

Comment: Yes expression is missing in where. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @samlee . . . Please explain what the logic is supposed to be doing.  Non-working SQL doesn't usually do a good job of explaining this.

Comment: The `where` clause requires a boolean expression, but your sub-select doesn't return a boolean it returns a number

Answer (score 0):

Whole `select max() ...` part returns one value but after `where` clausule you should have expression like `where something = 1`.
I can only guess what you want to achieve with this query, but maybe it should look like this:

```
select substr(phone,0,3) as area_code from customer 
where area_code in (select max(substr(phone,0,3)) from customer);
```

P.S. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL))

Comment: You might want to repeat 'substr(phone,0,3)' in the WHERE clause instead of area_code, because you can't normally refer to an alias directly in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an error code with the maximum number of users, then you would typically phrase this as:

```
select substr(phone, 1, 3) as area_code
from customer
group by substr(phone, 1, 3) 
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Window functions are also commonly used for this:

```
select area_code
from (select substr(phone, 1, 3) as area_code,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from customer
      group by substr(phone, 1, 3) 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that `rank()` will return multiple rows if there are ties for the most common area code.